# Are argc & argv useless in Windows?

Tags: c, windows

In linux, argc and argv count arguments in terminal. But in Windows, I can't find anywhere to put the second arguments. Actually every time when I run the program, it creates that ugly black window and I even have no chance to give any argument. So are these two variables useless in Windows platform? Or there's another way to use it?

Comment: You should run console programs from a console and GUI programs from a GUI. Running console programs from a GUI is awkward. (If your question is whether they're useless in GUI programs, no they're not. They're very useful for selecting parameters that the program must read before the GUI initializes.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you start from the command prompt, you can give the arguments there.

> Start menu -> run -> "cmd" -> "MyProgram.exe arg1 arg2"

Comment: I don't know how to use commands in WIndows. Is that command.exe or cmd.exe or something else?

Comment: @user1229490 start menu -> run -> cmd

Answer (score 4):

If you start your program from the command line as in linux, you are still able to pass arguments. Also if you create a Shortcut to an .exe you can place arguments for it there.

Answer (score 4):

The `int main(int argc, char**argv)` interface is defined by *C* standards, so if Windows claims to have a *ISO C99* compliant language implementation it should accept them, at least on the command line.

Comment: "if Windows claim to be ISO C99" Er, Windows is not a C compiler and doesn't make that claim.

Comment: ISO C99 works the other way around: ` argc`  is the number of arguments passed by the OS, which can be 0 (when the OS doesn't even pass the program name). I.e. C99 doesn't put any obligations on the OS.

Answer (score 1):

argc and argv are very usefull if properly used as arguments of main(). Probably the mistake (from my assumption) you are doing is that you are double clicking the executable rather than running the exe in the console and hence you are not getting a chance for entering the second argument.

In case you have document which states the proper use of the executable, then is should be followed and in case you have the source then check in that what arguments the main accepts and provide them in the command prompt after the name of the executable.

`myexe.exe arg1 arg2`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use them in windows. As it needs command line interface you can use cmd.
Just compile your program and run your program on cmd like this: "filename" "argument1" "argumrnt2"...
For eg:[look here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DV1Cz.png)

Answer (score -1):

you can use argc argv[] in windows also one option is save your program in the bin folder of your c compiler may be turbo c++ or code blocks or whatever

I  uses code blocks then open your cmd move to bin folder usind cd command then compile your program using command gcc *.c it will give you a file named a.exe like in linux it gives a.out the for run you can use command simply
a "argument1" " argument2"...... OR
a.exe "argument1" " argument2"......

i prefers first obviously every one prefers short command

second option is set environment variable of c by process given below
1.copy address of bin folder of compile
2.open properties of "This pc" left side press advance sysytem settings 
3.press environment variable
4.under user variables press new 
5.put varible name as Path p capital value paste the address copied from bin
press ok ok ok
now you can save your program anywhere and compile and run using cmd

__________****ENJOY****_________________