# C - Reading a File from Command Line?

Tags: c, unix

Suppose I had a file that I wanted to read.

```
./a.out file // where file is a argument
```

The Program being:

```
     //program.c

        #include <stdio.h>
        #include <stdlib.h>


        int main(int argc, char *argv[])
        {  
        char ch, file_name[25] = argv[1]; //??? Is the issue here?
        FILE *fp;

         fp = fopen(file_name,"r");  

        if( fp == NULL )
       {
          perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }

       printf("The contents of %s file are :\n", file_name);

       while( ( ch = fgetc(fp) ) != EOF )
          printf("%c",ch);

       fclose(fp);
       return 0;

        }
```

**EDITED:**

When compiling with gcc

```
gcc program.c
```

> program.c: file not recognized: File format not recognized

Is the error Im getting.

Comment: Why not compile and try? I am pretty sure it will not destroy our world.

Comment: Cannot use SSH atm, dont have access to Unix

Comment: Just try `printf("%s\n", argv[1]);` and see if it is correct.

Comment: This is not *nix dependent, but just for the sake of noting it: run a vm locally.

Comment: If you are currently limited by working on a windows machine, you could install cygwin (http://www.cygwin.com/) which makes all the unix tools you need for this available on your windows machine.

Comment: if you compile this in unix, you'll (probably) have one of two outputs `a.out` or `program`.  So, to run the program, it wouldn't be `./program.c file` but instead `./a.out file` or `./program file`.  The answer comes from your `cc` line.  If you type `cc program.c` the resultant program will be `a.out` and the other form would be `cc -o program program.c` which would result in an executable named `program`

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10878128/are-argc-argv-useless-in-windows

Comment: Ok Im using Cygwin.  When compiling: "gcc program
program: file not recognized: File format not recognized" Why is this?

Comment: You will get a warning for the uninitialized variable `file_name` and random trash (which may or may not be visible) in your `printf` string.

Comment: Wait. You want to know about `argv` or you need a 1-minute Introduction To How To Compile?

Comment: I am having an issue reading from the command line with such file. I know how to compile. The question has been edited.

Comment: The error message you're reporting ("File format not recognized") indicates that you're trying to run the wrong file, or you're compiling it incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//program.c                                                                                                                                                                                                         

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#define SIZEBUF 1024

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int   fd;
   char  buffer[SIZEBUF];

  if (argc < 2)
   {
    printf("Missing file\n");
    return (EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
  fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
  if (fd == -1)
   {
     printf("Some error occured\n");
     return (EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
  printf("The contents of %s file are :\n", argv[1]);
  while(read(fd, buffer, SIZEBUF) > 0 )
    printf("%s", buffer);
  close(fd);
  return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

But if you're in doubt, you could try printing the things in `argv`.